# Which filter can best remove horizontal vertical banding noises (hvbn) from image

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, noise, noise-reduction

I would like to know if among the OpenCV filter functions, is there a particular one that is suited to remove horizontal/vertical banding noise in an image? Like, for salt and pepper noise, Gaussian blur works best. Or, is the process of removing banding noise a combination of different filters?

Did try several filters already like bilateral, gaussian, median and blur(homogenous), but the vertical banding lines don't seem to disappear or significantly reduce, or sometimes the resulting image is just so smoothed. I'd prefer the image to be retained, only that the noise is removed.

I am interested to do the removal of noise in OpenCV, c++ in particular. Any basic steps, concepts or tutorial would be great. Thanks

The sample images are here which shows obvious marks of vertical bands of noise. These images are outputs of a scanner by the way.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1aXcXzD_OADMkNuNnJxNGw2NTA/edit?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1aXcXzD_OADNkFBbGgxU20yMjg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I could not see the images in your links.  For 'shot noise' typically Gaussian works pretty well.  In my experience, banding will occur less randomly.  Perhaps you could try to just subtracting it.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

1.find your lines

- for example search for repetitive bumps/edges on first derivation by x or y;
- then select only those which are in average period place
- and neighbouring lines/rows has also this bump near the same place

2.remove pixels of selected lines

- just take color before and after bump
- and interpolate between them (avg color for example)
- also in some case you can substract constant color from all pixels of the line
- depends on the color mixing mechanism which created those lines

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce vertical or horizontal noise by adjusting the kernel size using simple [blur](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=blur#blur) operation

Fir example for your vertical noised image you could use

```
blur(src,dst,Size(11,1));
```

Note that here the kernel size in vertical direction is higher value compared to horizontal.

See the image before and after filtering

[image]

[image]

Similarly for horizontal just use reverse kernel size like

```
blur(src,dst,Size(1,11));
```

See the result

[image]       [image]